# External web service redirects the user and posts data to my callback URL. How do I render the posted data to the user in an Express/Next.js app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

Any help would be hugely appreciated! Been stuck on this for a few days.

I have an Express/Next.js app where:

- I send the user to an external website
- user makes a payment
- external website redirects **and** posts data back to my callback URL.

So now I have the user on a `mysite.com/payment-complete` route but also want to display the data that was sent back.

I have an `app.post` endpoint to successfully grab the data:

```
app.post("/payment-complete", async (req, res) => {
  const transactionID = req.body.trans_id;
});
```

How would I pass the data to the user who is already on that route? Or pass the data before the page is rendered?

The flow of data is third party > my server > user and I'm not sure how to make this work.

I'd be grateful for any help/direction with this.

Comment: Using Ajax probably?

Comment: @Geert-Jan can you elaborate please?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone comes across this - the problem was that in Express (and other languages) you can't redirect or render a view for an AJAX POST request but you *can* if the POST request is coming from a submitted html form. The web service was in fact POST-ing the data and redirecting my users with a form and so I could render a view.

Following code worked using Handlebars templating engine to send the render.

```
router.post("/payment-ok", async (req, res) => {
  const transactionID = req.body.trans_id;
  return res.render("rendertest", { id: transactionID });
});
```

Should also possibly work with `app.render` to send a Next.js view instead, but I wanted to render from a separate routes file.